# How to make outgoing call via JAIN-SIP to asterisk

Tags: java, asterisk, communication, asteriskami, jain-sip

I try to migrate my project from asterisk-ami to SIP protocol. However, I couldn't find any examples to create outgoing call via jain sip. Some documentation mentions project [sip-communicator](http://sip-communicator.dev.java.net) but he is outdated.

**About project**: it's notification system via phone. It calls a person and after 2-3 calls interrupts the call. So I just need to call via astersik from my java code and interrupt the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JAIN-SIP is not a functionally comparable to asterisk-ami. However if you really just want to make an outbound call you can use [this example](https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip/blob/master/src/examples/simplecallsetup/Shootist.java) which originates a call from `sip:127.0.0.1:5060` to `sip:127.0.0.1:5070`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i can't find where i can set phone number

Comment: Typically you should put he target number in the "To" user here https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip/blob/master/src/examples/simplecallsetup/Shootist.java#L267 but you have to know how your destination interprets the numbers beforehand. Similarly the "From" user is the caller's number for caller id.